# Correct way to use forms to do an 'advanced search' with Flask?

Tags: python, forms, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to set up a little advanced search that allows to search products by *code, country,* and *title*. Inside my `views.py` I have:

```
@app.route('/advanced_search_results/<code>/<country>/<title>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def advanced_search_results(code, country, title):
    products = models.Product.query.filter_by(code=code, country=country, title=title).all()
    return render_template('advanced_search_results.html', products=products)   


@app.route('/advanced_search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def advanced_search():
    form = AdvancedSearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        code = form.code.data
        country = form.country.data
        title = form.title.data
        return redirect(url_for('advanced_search_results', code=code, country=country, title=title))
    return render_template('advanced_search.html', title='Advanced Search', form=form)
```

There are some obvious problems here, but what concerns me most is that an advanced search will end up at a url like *www.mysite.com/advanced_search_results/the_code/the_country/the_title*, and this string will only get longer as the search gets more advanced. Am I heading the right direction or am I missing a better way of handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use query strings - ie your URL would look like:

> mysite.com/advanced_search_results?country=USA&code=42&title=aTitle

```
from flask import request
@app.route('/advanced_search_results')
def adv_search_results():
    country = request.args.get('country')
    code = request.args.get('code')
    title = request.args.get('title')
    products = models.Product.query.filter_by(code=code, country=country, title=title).all()
    return render_template('advanced_search_results.html', products=products)
```

Also note that [unknown variables in url_for() will be appended as query parameters.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#url-building)